# Information from a file to another file using an alert box(PHP/JS/HTML)

Tags: javascript, php, html, forms

I have made a website for a restaurant(just a project not a real restaurant), and i want people to reserve online, so i have made a php file to save the information as you can see in the file.

```
<?php
$bestand = "gegevens.txt";
$open = fopen($bestand,"a");
$nwRegel= $_POST['datum']."|".$_POST['tijd']."|".$_POST['aantal'];
fwrite($open,$nwRegel);
fclose($open);
echo ('Dank u voor uw reservering!<br> U word verwacht op: ' .$_POST['datum'] . '<br>');
echo ('U tafel is klaar om: ' .$_POST['tijd'] . '<br>');
echo ('Met het aantal personen: ' .$_POST['aantal'] . '<br>');
```

So as you can see i have echo'd the information but i actually want it to be an alert. the gegevens.txt file is the file were the information is being saved, and here i have the form where i need to get the information from.

```
<section id="reserveren">
    <div class="container">
        <h2 class="titel">Reserveren</h2>
        <form class="reserveren" action="Reserveren.php" method="post">
            Reservering datum: <input type="date" name="datum" value="datum">
            <br />Uw gewenste tijd: <input type="time" name="tijd" value="tijd">
            <br />Aantal Personen: <input type="number" name="aantal" value="aantal">
            <br /><input type="submit" value="Aanvragen" name="submit" class="submit">
        </form>
    </div>
</section>
```

i have tried it with javascript like this, i have seen this on another qeustion:

```
echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('');</script>";
```

but this didnt really work for me. Also i have seen a sort like solution with Ajax but i have never used Ajax before so it is hard to understand what i am doing and i want to know what i am doing in my form instead of just having a form pre made. so any ideas on how to make the information come in an alert box?

Comment: What do you mean by `echo`ing the script tags didn't work?

Comment: Not sure of what you want to do here. But if you want to have informations back without reloading your page, yes you have to use AJAX. It will call your php script and give what you want to your js without reloading